# project created with command prompt error in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

i have try to install react and i have installed it successfully.
project also create but i try to run it gives following error...
the error flows like...

react-script start

starting the development server...

events.Js:292
throw er; //unhandled 'error' event

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
.
.
.
errorno: 'ENOENT'
code: 'ENOENT'
syscall: 'spawnc cmd'
parh:'cmd'
..
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! demo-project@0.1.0 start: 'react-script start'
npm ERR! exit status 1

Comment: Have you tried changing the port of your development server?

Comment: yes i have try but no use